# how to stop checking condition with mousewheel direction

Tags: jquery, scroll

am trying to check scroll direction when hit '.box'. when I reach '.box' if I scrolldown body will turn yellow, when scroll up turn green. But I have problem when scroll already pass '.box', scroll condition is keep running, I try to bring it back to white in else wont work either.

How I can stop this condition?
Thank you

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var st = $(this).scrollTop();

  var box = $('.box').offset().top;
  var boxHeight = $('.box').height();
  if (st > box && st >= boxHeight) {
    $(window).bind('mousewheel', function(event) {
      if (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta >= 0) {
        $('body').css('background-color', 'green');
      } else {
        $('body').css('background-color', 'yellow');
      }
    });
  } else {
    $('body').css('background-color', 'white');
  }
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div class="box"></div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use jQuery `.off()` as described in the jQuery documentation, or my preferred method is to simply use a variable with condition statements to determine whether or not to act.

You should however use jQuery `.on(funct...)` instead of `.bind(functi...)` as this is being deprecated in newer versions of jQuery.

Snippet below, with comments

```js
var boxState = false;

$(window).on({
  scroll: function() {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop(),
      box = $('.box').offset().top,
      winHeight = $(this).height(),
      boxHeight = $('.box').height();

    boxState = (st < box + boxHeight && st + winHeight > box); // is box in window? if so boxState will be true
  },
  mousewheel: function(e) {
    var wheel = e.originalEvent.wheelDelta;
    if (wheel >= 0 && boxState) { // use the boxState variabel to determine whether or not to act
      $('body').css('background-color', 'green');
    } else if (wheel < 0 && boxState) {
      $('body').css('background-color', 'yellow');
    } else {
      $('body').css('background-color', 'white');
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

#monitor {
  position: fixed;
  left: 1em;
  bottom: 1em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div class="box"></div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div id='monitor'></div>
```